# ....title of js

Tags: javascript, image

Trying to change the image but having some trouble. This is what I have so far. When I click on the action, the image doesn't change.

```js
document.getElementById('action').addEventListener('click', function() {

    document.getElementById("01.jpg").src = "02.jpg"; 

    
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Header 1 </h1>
        <img id="photo" src="01.jpg" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <a id="action" href="#">Click Me to Modify This Page</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The id of your `img` is `"photo"`, not `"01.jpg"`

Comment: try adding `return false`

Comment: @DominikMatis why?

Comment: Usually the anchor will redirect after clicking, return false should provide that it won't redirect afaik

Comment: https://www.techiedelight.com/make-anchor-tag-refer-nothing-javascript/

Comment: You need to look on the console when you use javaScript to see what errors you get, for example when a user clicks on the link the error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null"` get logged, and that means that the selector method didn't find your element, and that's because `"01.jpg"` is the src value and not the id instead it should be `"photo"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in document.getElementById the id from your image and not the imagename.

```js
document.getElementById('action').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("photo").src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQGLpUYrlREGy0letrNu1q-Wl90fF8crtN7mg&usqp=CAU"; 
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Header 1 </h1>
    <img id="photo" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSqwJv6wgZh530ZXxBE2xeui6UtiJK2Uu-6UA&usqp=CAU" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <a id="action" href="#">Click Me to Modify This Page</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error here - `document.getElementById ("01.jpg")`. Instead of an image, you must provide your ID - `photo`.

```js
document.getElementById('action').addEventListener('click', function() {

    document.getElementById("photo").src = 'https://sun9-32.userapi.com/impf/c824201/v824201969/173424/ayWCFmi538s.jpg?size=200x0&quality=90&sign=b461a01af900c4374512c2b13455c25d&ava=1'; 

    
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Header 1 </h1>
        <img id="photo" src="01.jpg" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <a id="action" href="#">Click Me to Modify This Page</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```